# Proprietary nvidia pascal-10 support for ubuntu 16.04 and 16.10

Tags: drivers, 16.04, nvidia, xorg, 16.10

As described here you can add PPA for proprietary nvidia driver: [howto nvidia ubuntu](http://tipsonubuntu.com/2016/08/24/nvidia-367-44-support-titan-x-pascal-gtx-1060/)

But the comments shed a negative light on the stability.

Has somebody gathered some experience with the above described settings?
As for the Open Source Software noveau, there should be no 3D acceleration available at all!

Or is still the proverb valid: F*** nvidia?

Comment: As for now I will dump nvidia Pascal 10. I will wait for AMD Ryzen CPU and Vega 10 GPU and an OSS driver solution!